# A consistent Method Resolution Order couldn't be created (MRO error)

Tags: python, python-3.6, method-resolution-order

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print ("Base")

class childA(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print ('Child A')
        Base.__init__(self)

class childB(Base,childA):
    def __init__(self):
        print ('Child B')
        super(childB, self).__init__()


b=childB()
```

Inheritance would go as childB, Base, childA, Base and after applying MRO, it should become childB,childA,Base. But its throwing MRO error. why?

Comment: Why does `childB` inherit from `Base`? `childA` already does that, so why do it twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`childB` is attempting to inherit from `Base` **twice**, once through `childA` and once directly. Fix by removing the multiple inheritance on `childB`.

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print ("Base")

class childA(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print ('Child A')
        Base.__init__(self)

class childB(childA):
    def __init__(self):
        print ('Child B')
        super(childB, self).__init__()

b=childB()
```